# Toggling the meteor accounts ui/password login

Tags: meteor

I have a "sign up" button which shows the basic accounts-ui login service, with the basic email/password login. But to close it, you have to click the "Close" button. I am wondering whether there is a work around which when I click the "sign up" button that it toggles the login div. I've tried a lot of Javascript work arounds, but nothing seems to work for me at the moment.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You may create a custom register/login: https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-custom-login-registration-form-with-meteor/

Answer (score 1):

Best way to proceed is to create your own custom login. Use meteor functions for signUp/signIn as you dont want to compromise on security. Give these docs a read and use the functions as per your convenience : https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html, https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html